# bash argument parsing in function

Tags: bash, function, arguments

Is the a workaround to parsing the bash script arguments in an function

run command:
    ./script.sh -t -r -e

script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# parse argument function
parse_args() {
echo "$#"   #<-- output: 0
}


# main
echo "$#"   #<-- output: 3

# parsing arguments
parse_args
```

Comment: I now the reason for the 'output 0' but is there a way to do the argument parsing in an extra function?

Comment: Add `$@` after `parse_args `.

Comment: thx Cyrus. Solution: parse_args $@

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$#` evaluates to the number of parameters in the current scope. Since each function has its own scope and you don't pass any parameters to `parse_args`, `$#` will always be 0 inside of it.

To get the desired result, change the last line to:

```
parse_args "$@"
```

[The special variable `"$@"`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#index-_0040) expands to the positional parameters of the current (top-level) scope as separate words. Subsequently they are passed to the invocation of `parse_args`.

Comment: Nice answers. And great example you added to my answer!